# Internet Explorer fails to understand the coordinates of overflowing div

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, overflow

I have an element that is inside a container with overflow:auto in order to make it scrollable for small screens. When the screen is narrow enough and the contained element is wider than the container (be it that the right side of the contained element is greater or equal than that of the container, or that the leftmost point of the contained element is smaller or equal than that of the container), a button with an arrow would appear on each side of the container, and when the scroll has reached it's maximum right or left, the respective button would be disabled and grayed out (this is exactly what the code below does). This function gets executed each time I press one of the elements inside the contained element, when I press one of the scroll buttons mentioned before, and also when the component mounts (I´m using React).
Now, my code works perfectly on Chrome, Firefox and Edge, but with IE, the right button gets disabled and grayed out immediately, and the cause of this is that IE considers that the contained element's rightmost coordinate is that of the container! Furthermore, when I scroll the contained element to the left, the coordinates of the right side of the contained element are those of the part of it where it was cut at the beginnig (so they decrease and are less than the rightmost coordinate of the container, although in some cases it still overflows it to the right).

I don't know how to get IE to interpret that the contained element's rightmost side is where the element really ends and not where it stops being visible (and keeping that point be the end point when scrolled).

So, the overflowWrapper is the container, with overflow:auto, and the tabsPanel is the contained element.

Here is my javascript code in case it helps:

````
const grayOutButtons = () => {
  const wrapper = document.getElementById('tabsOverflowWrapper');
  const overflowWrapperRect = wrapper.getBoundingClientRect();
  const tabsPanel = document.getElementById('tablistPanel');
  const tabsPanelRect = tabsPanel.getBoundingClientRect();
  const tabsPanelMargin = tabsPanel.style.marginLeft.match(/[0-9]/g).join('');

  if (Math.floor(tabsPanelRect.right) <= Math.ceil(overflowWrapperRect.right)) {
    $('#rightScrollBtn')
      .css({ opacity: '0.2' })
      .prop('disabled', true);
    $('#leftScrollBtn')
      .css({ opacity: '1' })
      .prop('disabled', false);
  } else if (tabsPanelRect.left + parseInt(tabsPanelMargin) >= overflowWrapperRect.left) {
    $('#rightScrollBtn')
      .css({ opacity: '1' })
      .prop('disabled', false);
    $('#leftScrollBtn')
      .css({ opacity: '0.2' })
      .prop('disabled', true);
  } else {
    // $('#rightScrollBtn').attr('disabled');
    $('#rightScrollBtn')
      .css({ opacity: '1' })
      .prop('disabled', false);
    // $('#leftScrollBtn').attr('disabled');
    $('#leftScrollBtn')
      .css({ opacity: '1' })
      .prop('disabled', false);
  }
  console.log(`tabpanel right: ${Math.floor(tabsPanelRect.right)}`);
  console.log(`overflowwrapper right: ${Math.ceil(overflowWrapperRect.right)}`);
};```
````

Comment: are you `float`ing anything in the non-existent HTML + CSS?

Comment: @Jaromanda X nope.

Comment: can you post the Enough code to reproduce the problem as in [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).